# Validation Error in RSpec before(:each) block has weird behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

REVISED: the error here was that I was storing several different models in the same hash. This was an internal way with how I was constructing the array. Anyway, I apologize for the error here. There was no way one could have answered the question with how I asked it.

So I have an RSpec before(:each) block in a controller spec. My example model has a status field and the following validation:

```
  class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    STATI = [ "vacant", "deleted", "deactivated"]
    ...
    validates :status, :inclusion => { :in => STATI }
    ...
  end
```

And in my spec, I have the following code.

```
  describe Controller do
    ...
    describe "some methods" do
      before(:all) do
        @models = []
        10.times { @models << Factory(:model) }
      end
      before(:each) do
        @models.each { |m| m.update_attributes(:status => "vacant") }
      end
      ...
    end
  end
```

When I run the spec, all the other describe blocks run fine. It pulls an an error to the effect of:
      ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
      Validation failed: Status is not included in the list
and points to the line where it says m.update_attributes(:status => "vacant").

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What status do you create with `Factory.model`?

Comment: side note: "@models = 10.times.map { Factory(:model) }" or "@models = FactoryGirl.create_list(:model, 10)"

Comment: apneadiving, the factory uses the same status: "vacant"

Comment: i should also there is a similar question here, but again my problem is not solved with that solution and does not make since in this context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416381/problems-with-validates-inclusion-of-acts-as-tree-and-rspec

Comment: - tokland; for some reason that didn't work for me. I got uninitialized constant Factory Girl. Factory works fine. I have   gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0' installed

Comment: Another side note: Be careful with `before(:all)` any data created here will not be deleted from the database at the end, you will need to delete it in an `after(:all)` or use database cleaner. See [link][https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/issues/2] for reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following in your model definition:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATI = %w[vacant deleted deactivated]
  ...
  validates :status, :inclusion => STATI
  ...
end
```

The %w is preferred syntax for creating an array of strings, and allows the removal of `"` and `,` from your array definition.

You do not need the `:in =>` for an inclusion validation.